# Slow SwiftMailer and Internal Server Error GoDaddy

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am trying to develop an mass email system (at max sending no more than 200 emails at one time) using SwiftMailer, but it executes very slowly. It works when sending out plain text emails, though emails with attachments take a while.

When sending an email with about 1.5MB of attachments to 163 users, sometimes I would get a 500 Internal Server Error, but I would check my error logs and they wouldn't say anything (probably because I'm using shared Linux hosting on GoDaddy). It takes about 2 minute and 21 seconds before the error appears, and there were only 114 SMTP relays instead of 163. **EDIT:** I've added this code to the top of my script, but am still having the same problems.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout', 500);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 500);
```

Here is the error that appears:

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mitsapp.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I already have the code in a try/catch block, but that doesn't show me any errors currently. I'm thinking the issue is the amount of queries that occur in the script. If so, how do I optimize them? If not, how could I solve this problem? Here is the code starting at adding attachments.:

```
//Add attachments
if(isset($_FILES['attachments'])) {
    $attCount = count($_FILES['attachments']['name']);
    $x = 0;
    while($x < $attCount) {
        if(!isset($_FILES['attachments']['name'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $message->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath("uploads/".$_FILES['attachments']['name'][$x]));
        $x++;
    }
}

//Sender Details
$message->setFrom('no-reply@mitsapp.com');
$message->setSender('no-reply@mitsapp.com');
try {$reply = Swift_Validate::email($_POST['reply']);} catch(Exception $e) {header("Location: ../communicate.php?error=2");}
$message->setReturnPath($_POST['reply']);
$message->setReplyTo($_POST['reply']);

//Send the message
require "connect.php";
$failedRecipients = array();
$numSent = 0;
$sendTo = $_POST['sendTo'];
$emails = array();
foreach ($sendTo as $ID) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".strtolower($_SESSION["mid"])."_current_roster WHERE ID=".$ID;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error sending email. ".mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)  > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $emails[] = $row['email'];
        }
    }
}
foreach($emails as $address) {
    $message->setTo($address);
    $numSent += $mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
}
```

There is more code after that which works fine there there isn't an internal server error, but doesn't run when there is.